# Moving datastores between Models in ODI 12c using Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, oracle-data-integrator, datastore

I want to move datastores that belongs in one Model to another Model. I have come to understand that whatever that can be done in ODI GUI, can also be done through using Java api reference for Oracle data integrator. However, i can't seem to find any methods or classes that enables me to move a datastore from one model to another.

There is a possibility to remove the datastore completely and then recreate it in another model, but this approach requires you to change references to mappings and a lot of other settings.

Is there anyway i can move a datastore from a model to another in ODI using the java api reference ?

Comment: the question is about copying table structure from one database to another using java?

Comment: Not exactly. It is about copying table structure from one model folder to another in the Designer tab in Oracle Data Integrator.